# MissingPackageNameException when trying to read a package inside WEB-INF from test method

Tags: java, web-applications, drools

I need to read a file inside the WEB-INF/exam folder from my test class. I am getting the following exception when ever I run the test

> org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder$MissingPackageNameException:

```
'PATH = "C:\Project\TestApp\WebContent\WEB-INF\Rule\"

private static RuleBase ruleBase;
File rFile = new File(PATH, "file name");
        try {
FileReader reader = new FileReader(rFile);
ruleBase = RuleBaseLoader.getInstance().loadFromReader(rFile );

}'
```

Can some one help figure out what I am doing wrong? I am unable to figure out wht the issue is, till now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't put a package name in your rule file. Just put "package mypackage" (or whatever) at the top.

Alternatively, if you're only trying to load a rule file, then you don't need to build a package.

```
KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
builder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(ruleFilePath), 
            ResourceType.DRL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..I got the issue fixed , there was some issue with the path.